# Can I use two values of a foreign key in on table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a 'users' table, and there is also a table 'alerts'. And in the 'alert' table, I want to use 'users.id' two times representing two different users of a 'users' table as a foreign keys in 'alert' table.

Is it possible? if not then what will be the alternate solution? Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Two fk's, no problem at all.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for your answer. Can you guide me more how I implement it.

Comment: You can have more than one FK in a table

Comment: Do the same you'd do for one FK but twice.

Comment: is it a good practice to accomplish the scenario or there is a better solution for it??

Comment: Of course it's possible. By the way, this is one of the flagship cases against natural joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would express this as:

```
create table alerts (
    . . . ,
    user_id_from int,
    user_id_to int,
    foreign key (alerts_user_id_from) references users(user_id),
    foreign key (alerts_user_id_to) references users(user_id)
);
```

I just made up the column names to give you an example of how it would work.